# Having an issue in building an autocomplete function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create my own autocomplete functionality from scratch. The code below checks for the result within the `result` class. Then the value within the `result` class loops through the `name` classes. If a particular string matches then adds a class called `display`

The problem I'm having right now is that the class `display` will only be added once it has an exact match and not a partial match (meaning I have to complete the whole string). If I tried removing or erasing the value inside the `input textfield`, it does not seem to remove the classes that is currently added

```js
$('.name-box').on("input", function() {
  let value = $(this).val();
  let result = $(this).text(value);
  $('.result').text(value);

  // $(this).find('.name-' + val).addClass('display');
  $('.name-list .name').each(function() {
    if ($('.result').text() == $(this).text()) {
      $(this).addClass('display');
    } else if ($('.result').val() != $(this).val()) {
      $(this).removeClass('display');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="name-box" type="text" />
</form>

<ul class="name-list">
  <li class="name name-noeldelacruz" data-bindhandle="@noeldelacruz">@noeldelacruz</li>
  <li class="name name-john" data-bindhandle="@john">@john</li>
  <li class="name name-joe" data-bindhandle="@joe">@joe</li>
  <li class="name name-james" data-bindhandle="@james">@james</li>
  <li class="name name-jake" data-bindhandle="@jake">@jake</li>
  <li class="name name-jade" data-bindhandle="@jade">@jade</li>
</ul>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: There many ways to do this.  You might want to try a different approach and play with these fiddles.  https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/cS2bL/  http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Wz7Vy/ https://jsfiddle.net/landsapi/7xwms73m/

Answer (score 1):

You could check for partial matches like so:

```
if ($(this).text().includes($('.result').text())) {
  $(this).addClass('display');
} else {
  $(this).removeClass('display');
}
```